# How to get FireError SubComponent paramerter in error handler

Tags: ssis

When we invoke the Dts.Events.FireError method in a script task, we provide the description as the third parameter.  This is available to error handlers in the variable System::ErrorDescription.  Is the second parameter called SubComponent available to error handlers anywhere, and if so where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no variables called subcomponent.  This is a field that you can use to help classify the source of an error.  Suppose you had a script that downloaded a file and then unzipped it.  You can use the subcomponent parameter to identify the source of the error.  i.e.:

```
        try
        {
            //download file
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Download File", e.Message, "", 0);
        }

        try
        {
            //unzip file
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Unzip File", e.Message, "", 0);
        }
```

The logged error could look like this: `Unzip File: File does not exist`
This could be a helpful pattern for catching generic errors that could apply to different sections of the script.

`System::ErrorDescription` will only be available in the event handler, but could be handled in a similar way if you scoped the event to particular components.

Leave it as an empty string if you do not need it.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for such a slow response Mark Wojciechowicz.  I very much appreciate your help.  So this shows in SSIS native logging but cannot be used in one's own event error handlers.  This is what I expected. Thank you.